# Vertically centering text within a button

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertically align a button's text to the center. We're using Bootstrap buttons on a variety of devices and it works well for all, except on a particular device where it doesn't.

This is what it looks like on Chrome and on most devices: [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JuGR.png), [Chrome DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veDdR.png)

And this is what it looks like on our device: [Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7ZWP.png), [Device DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZqrT.png)

The text on our device is aligned slightly above center. I've tried changing the line height, using css reset, css normalize and have messed with a few other css properties as well but none of them could center the text vertically.

These are our overrides for the button

```css
.btn {
  font-family: $open-sans;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-color: #cfcfcf;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

The button:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn">Close</button>
```

We also tried using `<a />` and `<input>` tags as done in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#button-tags), but to no avail:

```html
<a class="btn" role="button">Close</a>
<input class="btn" type="button" value="Close">
```

The major difference I see between the two is that the text within the element (the blue bit in DevTools) is aligned to the top in the case of our device, whereas it's aligned in the center of the element in other browsers and I can't figure out how to normalize it across the two.

Not sure if it'd be helpful, but the target device where this fails uses Android System WebView 74.0.3729.186. Fairly old, but it is what it is.

**EDIT**:
If you look at the DevTools pictures, the issue isn't with aligning the content (inner blue box) to the center of the button, the content is correctly centered within the button. The issue is that the text isn't correctly centered within the content. Changing the `line-height` property doesn't do anything as it still maintains the gap below the text within the content box.

Thought it might have to do with the font having too much internal padding, but changed the font to get the same results.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68253993/how-to-vertically-align-a-button-text-that-uses-the-vh-units/68257181) I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68257181/13446600) I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 issues:

1. padding-bottom: Check if you have equal padding top and bottom. By defualt, it should be `padding: .375rem .75rem;`.
2. line-height: Check if it is `24px`. You do not need to have it at alll since there is only one line. Set `line-height: 0`

```
.btn {
  font-family: $open-sans;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-color: #cfcfcf;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center !important;
  line-height: 0 !important; /* NEW */
}
```

---

If it does not work, use these two classes.

1. `d-flex`: make it flex
2. `aling-items-center`: vertically align its content in the center.

```
<button type="button" class="btn d-flex aling-items-center">Close</button>
```

Comment: Tried all the above, but nothing helped. The content is aligned correctly as per the css box model, but the text within the content box is not in the center. This is visible with certain fonts more than others