# How to vertically align a button text that uses the "vh" units?

Tags: html, css, button

I have a pretty simple example.

Normally, buttons vertically align their texts in the center.

However, given this example

```html
<button style="font-size: 18vh; height: 20vh;">
  Click me
</button>
```

You can clearly see that the top margin is taller than the bottom margin.

According to me, if the button height is 20vh and the font size is 18vh, then the margin above and below the text should be 1vh equally?

**Update**

It seems like people are suggesting `box-sizing: content-box;`. However, that does not work for me.

[image]

So I am wondering, if there is a way to make this aligned (with additional CSS or HTML) on all systems?

Answer (score 2):

You have the default padding and border applied to button and also `box-sizing` is set to `border-box` on button so everything is included in the height you defined which make you calculation wrong.

Use `box-sizing:content-box` to exclude padding and border:

```html
<button style="font-size: 18vh; height: 20vh;box-sizing:content-box">
  Click me
</button>
```

Comment: Hey, if I run your example, the margins are still incorrect.

Comment: Ah, I see there is a difference in Chrome vs Firefox (which I am using, hm).

Comment: @corgrath on my Firefox it's fine but I am not surprised if it behave differently based on OS or version because button are very special and depend a lot on your system

Comment: Is your snippet working on your Firefox? Meaning box-sizing content box fixes it?

Answer (score 1):

**#Use `box-sizing:content-box;`**

```html
<button style="font-size:18vh;height:20vh;box-sizing:content-box">Click me</button>
```

**#Try To Use `line-height:18vh;` Property**

```html
<button style="font-size:18vh;height:20vh;line-height:18vh">Click me</button>
```

**#Use `display:flex;` Or `display:inline-flex;` & `align-items:center;`**

```html
<button style="font-size:18vh;height:20vh;display:flex;align-items:center">Click me</button>
```

**#Try To Use `min-height:20vh;` Instead Of `height:20vh;`**

```html
<button style="font-size:18vh;min-height:20vh">Click me</button>
```

**#Try To Increase Height Property's Value To `height:22vh;`**

```html
<button style="font-size:18vh;height:22vh">Click me</button>
```

**#Try To Remove Height Property**

```html
<button style="font-size:18vh;">Click me</button>
```

**#Try To Decrease Font Size to `font-size:16vh;`**

```html
<button style="font-size:16vh;height:20vh">Click me</button>
```

**#Try To Use `font-size:3em;` Instead Of `font-size:18vh;`**

```html
<button style="font-size:3em;height:20vh">Click me</button>
```

**#Try To Use `height:1.3em;` Instead Of `height:20vh;`**

```html
<button style="font-size:18vh;height:1.3em">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I think line-height is near to the perfect answer for your question....

By the way Murari, these are a lot of solutions for one question. Good